# Chilkat mail UWP on Windows 10 Phone gives Class not registered error

Tags: uwp, windows-phone, chilkat

As explained in http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_uwp.asp, we installed the Chilkat UWP runtime via NuGet. We then used the following sample code:
https://www.example-code.com/csharp_winrt/smtp_simpleSend.asp
which should send an e-mail (using our own Chilkat unlock code).

However, although the program compiles and runs (we test it on a Nokia Phone by deploying it straight from Visual Studio on the device) we directly get an exception on the first line:

Chilkat.MailMan mailman = new Chilkat.MailMan();

InnerException is *Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))*

EDIT: I actually DID  find a solution. I had to copy the Chilkat.dll in the same directory where the Package.appxmanifest was located (down from the subdirectory bin\Release). This doesn't mean it now works. Chilkat logs (part of it:)               smtpAuthenticate:
                This SMTP server did not list authentication methods.
                Defaulting to LOGIN authentication method.
                login_method: LOGIN
                auth_login:
                      SmtpCmdSendFailed: AUTH LOGIN
                    --sendCmdToSmtp
                  --smtpSendGet2
                  AUTH LOGIN failed
                --auth_login
                Failed to login using LOGIN method
              --smtpAuthenticate

I use the same settings as the e-mail program uses, as far as I can see.

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: I actually DID  find a solution. I had to copy the Chilkat.dll in the same directory where the Package.appxmanifest was located (down from the subdirectory bin\Release).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that Chilkat abandoned support for Windows Phone many years ago.  (Windows Phone was a complete boondoggle..)